# There is still an error when `include` a relative path after `app.set`

Tags: javascript, path, ejs, relative-path

I have a nodejs project created by express-generator. This is the part of tree view of my project:

```
MyProject/
 |-- routes/
 |    |-- content.js
 |-- views/
 |    |-- contents/
 |    |    |-- bh/
 |    |         |-- bh_1.ejs
 |    |         |-- bh_2.ejs
 |    |-- content.ejs
 |-- app.js
```

In `app.js`, I have defined the base path for `include`:

```js
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

In `routes/content.js`, I have rendered the top EJS file `views/content.ejs`:

```js
var params = {
    path_bh_1: './contents/bh/bh_1.ejs',
    path_bh_2: './contents/bh/bh_2.ejs'
}

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('content', params);
});
```

In `views/content.ejs`, I have included the second EJS file:

```html
<%- include(path_bh_1); %>
```

In `views/bh/bh_1.ejs`, I have included the third one:

```html
<%- include(path_bh_2); %>
```

In `views/bh/bh_2.ejs`, there are normal HTML statements:

```html
<p>xxx</p>
```

But when I visit my website, the browser shows the error message: `Could not find the include file "contents/bh/bh_2.ejs"`. And I modified `routes/content.js`:

```js
var params = {
    path_bh_1: './contents/bh/bh_1.ejs',
    path_bh_2: '../../contents/bh/bh_2.ejs' // the path is modified
}
```

It works. I think it is weird. `app.set` can only control the top-layer `include` operation? Any answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you set view engine?  `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`

Comment: @kedarsedai I have set it because of the express-generator.

Comment: Any reason to write `var params = { path_bh_1: './contents/bh/bh_1.ejs',}` because `res.render('sending ejs file')` woks simply